# Maximize $x^2 + y^2$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 = 1 - xy$

Tags: optimization, analytic-geometry, nonlinear-optimization

The equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1 - xy$ represents an ellipse. I am trying to show that its major axis is along $y=-x$ and find the vertex. To find the vertex I tried to find the vector in the ellipse with the greatest norm, which is equivalent to maximizing $x^2 + y^2$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 = 1 - xy$. How can I approach this?

(The maximum value of the objective function $x^2 + y^2$ seems to be 2. If I start out by assuming this I am able to show that the function cannot exceed this value. But this is kind of doing it in reverse as I start by evaluating the function at $y=-x=1.$ This also doesn't prove that $y=-x$ is the only optimal solution. How would I do it without "guessing" the solution first?)

Comment: This type of problems can be solved using augmented Lagrangian method, which puts the restriction equation in the objective function with a penalty (the infactible points are penalised in order to preserve the factibility in the original problem).

Comment: You can perform a change of variables using linear algebra so that this equation reduces to the "usual" equation of an ellipse and this will give you what the major and minor axes are

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to avoid calculus and use linear algebra instead (to each their own!), let us write down this equation in a different way.

With matrices, if we set

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2}& 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
then this equation is the same as $\textbf{x}^TA \textbf{x} = 1$ with $\textbf{x} = (x ,y)^T$.

Now, using linear algebra we know symmetric matrices can be orthogonally diagonalized so we get

$A = PDP^T = PDP^{-1}$ where $$P = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
 1& 1 
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{3}{2} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So, this says that the major and minor axes of this quadratic are along $(-1, 1)^T$ and $(1,1)^T$ so exactly along the lines $y = x$ and $y= -x$.

The reason this works is that in the coordinates given by $P$ (or rather $P^T$), you end up with the equation of a circle in standard position i.e. something like $u^2 + v^2 = 1$ where $(u, v)^T = P^T (x,y)^T$. So $P$ gives you the directions along which to transform the circle into an ellipse, and $D$ tells you by how much to stretch along those axes.

Answer (score 3):

If$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2\quad\text{and}\quad g(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy,$$then you want to know the maximum of $f$ under the restriction that $g(x,y)=1$. In order to do so, you can solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}f_x(a,b)=\lambda g_x(a,b)\\f_y(a,b)=\lambda g_y(a,b)\\g(a,b)=1\end{array}\right.\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}2a=2\lambda a+\lambda b\\2b=2\lambda b+\lambda a\\a^2+b^2-ab=1\end{array}\right.$$The first two equations are a system of two linear equations, depending upon a parameter $\lambda$:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}(2-2\lambda)a-\lambda b=0\\-\lambda a+(2-2\lambda)b=0.\end{array}\right.\label{a}\tag1$$The determinant of the matrix of coefficients of the system \eqref{a} is $3\lambda^2-8\lambda+4$ whose roots are $2$ and $\frac23$. If $\lambda$ is not one of these numbers, then the only solution of \eqref{a} is $(0,0)$, but $g(0,0)\ne1$. So, see what happens if $\lambda$ *is* one of those numbers:

- if $\lambda=2$, then the solutions are $\pm(1,-1)$;
- if $\lambda=\frac23$, then the solutions are $\pm\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$.

Since the value that $f$ takes at the first two points is $2$ and the values that it takes at the other two is $\frac23$, the maximum of $f$ is indeed $2$.

Comment: Good technique, very instructive. Often when I use Lagrange multipliers I’m left with a lengthy, rather ugly algebraic procedure to find the solutions, but this idea with the determinant cuts out a lot of it in a very satisfying way, very nice idea. (and one I’ll likely steal for myself where applicable)

Comment: That method works whenever both $f$ and $g$ are quadratic functions.

Comment: Yes of course, so that the partial derivatives are linear in $x$ and $y$ and we get a linear system. I'd just never seen someone take advantage of the linear system in that fashion in this type of problem, likely because my main exposure to the method was in school before we took linear algebra.

Comment: @StephenDonovan  I think, Algebra still works easily.

Comment: @lonestudent There are different types of difficult, the algebra isn't difficult to grasp but it can get quite tedious, especially when you don't immediately see the best method.

Comment: Hope my answer is seen equivalent to using Lagrange Multiplier $\lambda$ method.

Answer (score 3):

$\Delta \thinspace \thinspace \rm {method \thinspace\thinspace works\thinspace .}$

You have :

$$
\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=a,\thinspace a\in\mathbb R\\
x^2+y^2+xy=1\end{cases}
$$

This implies that,

$$
\begin{cases}y=\frac {1-a}{x}\\
x^2+\frac{(a-1)^2}{x^2}-a=0\end{cases}
$$

Then, letting $x^2=u$, we have :

$$
\begin{align}&u+\frac {(a-1)^2}{u}-a=0\\
\implies &u^2-ua+(a-1)^2=0\end{align}
$$

This leads to:

$$
\begin{align}&\Delta_u=a^2-4(a-1)^2\geq 0\\
\implies &\frac 23\leq a\leq 2\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

The equality $a=2$ holds, iff when :

$$\begin{align}&u=\frac a2=1\\
\implies &(x,y)=\left(\pm 1,\mp 1\right)\end{align}$$

Thus, we obtain a global maximum :

$$
\begin{align}\max\left\{x^2+y^2\mid x^2+y^2=1-xy\right\}&=2\\
\rm {at} \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace (x,y)=\left(\pm 1\thinspace,\mp 1\right)\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\end{align}
$$

Similarly, since $a\geq \frac 23$, then we obtain a global minimum :

$$
\begin{align}\min\left\{x^2+y^2\mid x^2+y^2=1-xy\right\}&=\frac 23\\
\rm {at} \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace (x,y)=\left(\pm \frac {\sqrt 3}{3},\thinspace \pm \frac {\sqrt 3}{3}\right)\end{align}
$$

This completes the answer .

Answer (score 3):

Using polar coordinates, then

$ x = r \cos \theta $

$ y = r \sin \theta $

So we want to maximize $ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 $ subject to $ r^2 = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2} r^2 \sin(2 \theta) $

Hence,

$ r^2 = \dfrac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2} \sin(2 \theta) } $

Clearly the maximum is when $ \sin(2 \theta) = -1 $, which corresponds to $ \theta = \dfrac{3 \pi}{4} $ and $ \theta = \dfrac{7 \pi}{4} $

At which points , $ r^2 = 2 $ (and this is the maximum value) and for the first value of $\theta$, we get

$ x = -1 , y = 1 $

And for the second value of $\theta$ we get

$ x = 1, y = -1 $

Answer (score 2):

*Substitutions* work much faster .

Let $\thinspace x=a+b,\thinspace y=a-b$, then you have :

$$\begin{align}&x^2+y^2=1-xy\\
\iff
&3a^2+b^2=1\end{align}$$

This leads to the following :

$\underline{\rm {Global\thinspace\thinspace maximum}}$

$$\begin{align}x^2+y^2&=2(a^2+b^2)\\
&=2(a^2+1-3a^2)\\
&=2-4a^2\leq 2\end{align}$$

Equality occurs iff, when $a=0,\thinspace |b|=1$, which corresponds to $\left(x,y\right)=\left(\pm 1,\mp 1\right)\thinspace . $

$\underline {\rm {Global\thinspace\thinspace minimum }}$

$$\begin{align}x^2+y^2&=2(a^2+b^2)\\
&=2\left(\frac {1-b^2}{3}+b^2\right)\\
&=\frac 23\left(2b^2+1\right)\geq\frac 23\end{align}$$

Equality occurs iff, when $b=0,\thinspace |a|=\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}$, which corresponds to $\left(x,y\right)=\left(\pm \frac {\sqrt 3}{3},\pm \frac {\sqrt 3}{3}\right).$

This completes the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If looking at a generalization is interesting the following:

Let $(f,g)$ be given object and constraint function respectively, Euler-Lagrange equation (in calculus of variations approach) can be also expressed as

$$\frac{f_{x}}{ f_{y}}=\frac{g_{x}}{ g_{y}}$$

$$\frac{2x}{2y}=\frac{2x+y}{2y+x}$$

which simplifies to

$$ x+y=0,~ x-y=0~ $$

The straight line pair intersects the constraint function graph $g(x,y)$ (green) at  ***four points*** solved which are shown at minimum and maximum respectively :

$$ D1=(\frac{ 1}{ \sqrt 3},\frac{ 1}{ \sqrt 3}),D2=(\frac{- 1}{ \sqrt 3},\frac{- 1}{ \sqrt 3}), ~ E1=(-1,1),E2=( 1,-1); $$

[image]

The choice between the extrema is decided by the Hessian with second partial derivatives. This approach gives insight also to the sign of Gauss curvature of the constraint function

$$z= g (x,y)$$

at these points in 3-space.

Answer (score 1):

A conic can be brought to canonical form with only one translation and one rotation. In this example the center of the conic is $(0,0)$, so we need only a rotation. Since $x^2-xy+y^2=1$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, without the formula, the rotation angle is easily $45^{\circ}$. Let, $P=(x,y)$ be old coordinates and $P'=(x',y')$ be new coordinates and $R_{\theta}$ be rotation transformation about the origin $\theta$ degrees. Then $P'=R_{45^{\circ}}P$ or in other words, $P=R_{-45^{\circ}}P'$ which gives
$$(x,y)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}x'+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}y',-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}x'+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}y').$$
Substituting this in the ellipse equation and omiting dashes easily gives
$$\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2/3}=1.$$
The vertices of this new ellipse is $\pm(\sqrt2,0)$ and $\pm(0,\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3})$. Now we have to rotate back these vertices by $R_{-45^{\circ}}=\left[\begin{matrix}\cos(-45^{\circ})&-\sin(-45^{\circ})\\\sin(-45^{\circ})&\cos(-45^{\circ})\end{matrix}\right]$. We get $\pm(1,-1)$ and $\pm(\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3})$.